# How to register custom type converters in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails

I found the documentation for [how to create a custom type converter with Spring 3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert), but I can't find any examples of registering the converter in Grails so that `bindData` can use it.

I tried adding this configuration to the conf/spring/resources.groovy file:

```
conversionService(org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean) {
    converters {
        com.initech.reports.tps.StringToFooConverter
    }   
}
```

This ends up stepping on something, because as soon as I add the converter in I get a stacktrace on startup like this:

> 2012-06-21 10:09:50,614 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  -
>   Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name
>   'FooApprovers': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type
>   [org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection] while
>   setting bean property 'schemaCollection'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type
>   'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]' for property 'xsds'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to
>   convert value "{/WEB-INF/ws/FooApproversService.xsd}" from type
>   'java.lang.String[]' to type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from 'java.lang.String' to
>   'org.springframework.core.io.Resource'
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'FooApprovers': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)' of type
>   [org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection] while
>   setting bean property 'schemaCollection'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type
>   'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]' for property 'xsds'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to
>   convert value "{/WEB-INF/ws/FooApproversService.xsd}" from type
>   'java.lang.String[]' to type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from 'java.lang.String' to
>   'org.springframework.core.io.Resource'    at
>   org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)     at
>   grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)  at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
>     at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
>     at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)    at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)   at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)     at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:33)   at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)  at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)   at
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)   at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)    at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)   at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 (includes Spring 3.0.5).

So apparently there is some other way type converters have been getting added and I messed that up by configuring the conversion service explicitly? Is there a way to register a custom type converter without stepping on other converters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for custom property editors i guess.

You will need to create your custom property editor, and a property editor registrar and then register your registrar in resources.groovy - After that bindDate should be able to use that

See this [article](http://omaha-seattle.blogspot.in/2010/02/custom-grails-property-editor.html)